# authentication using middleware.ts in NEXT.js 13

Tags: typescript, authentication, authorization, middleware, next.js13

I am currently coding an authentication system for my next.js app. My app has a login and user dashboard route. I have used post request method using Async and await to call API and store the JWT token in Session storage when the user logs in successfully(with the correct username and password). So when a user tries to go to the dashboard page, I want to check if the user is logged in (data exists in session storage) and check whether the token is stored in session storage or not. I think it is better to check it in middleware. So how can I access session storage in middleware to check user is logged in or not? Allow users to access the route or not. I tried to access session storage to check the user authentication status but it only sends a null value. I think it is because the middleware process is on the server side and session storage is on the client side. So how can I do this? Any idea?

```js
const userToken = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? sessionStorage.getItem('userToken') : null;
console.log("User Token:", userToken);
```

I tried this code to call a token from Session storage but it keeps sending me a Null value